# Can I download apps to this iPod Touch 2nd Generation?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, ipod-touch, ipod, authentication

I use an iPod Touch 2nd Generation running iOS 6.1.6 to listen to music absent from streaming platforms.
But when I go to the App Store and try to download apps, I get the message:

***"Your Apple ID or Password is incorrect"***

I have checked many times and the password is correct.

My other devices send me a message that a device is trying to connect but allowing doesn't initiate the download.

Has Apple Store access been disabled for these older devices, or is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things get complicated with [Two Step and Two Factor authentication and Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152). They are not the same and easily confused.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

> **What if I use two-factor authentication on a device running older software?**
> If you use two-factor authentication with devices running older OS versions—like an Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation)—you might be asked to add your six-digit verification code to the end of your password when signing in. Get your verification code from a trusted device running iOS 9 and later or OS X El Capitan and later, or have it sent to your trusted phone number. Then type your password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field

You may have to check which you have, then try validating the “old version” steps for what your account has enabled.

Comment: Brilliant! Typing the auth code after the password worked. The app I was trying to get was incompatible, but might be useful for future reference! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice work too, having the version searchable will help others I am sure @MicroMachine